# EventCallbackMethod overhead w/GUI App w/ electron

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sqlite, electron

hopefully you can help me to reduce my handler overhead ;-)

Currently I'm writing an GUI App with electron, using a SQLite Database and displaying the stuff on GUI.

The workflow currently goes a little like this:

- user clicks on a Button in the GUI
- button calls a JavaScript Function
- function calls ipc.SendSync(...)
- which calls DB.getCustomers(), which is a wrapper for Database stuff
- result is then JSON.stringify'ed to get it through ipc event arguments
- which is parsed and rendered as a table

I want to get rid of wrapping all the:

```
ipc.on('db-getCustomers', function (event, arg) {
  console.log('my-getCustomers  got called');
  event.returnValue = JSON.stringify(dataBase.getCustomers());
});
```

Is there any way I can avoid all the overhead/boilerplate of this? Skipping the IPC wrapping and JSON stringify/parse?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hey thanks for Reply!  
  
First: stringify -> shame on me, works without  
  
Second:  
to clarify what I mean with all the Overhead is:  
  
My Database Wrapper Class:  
`module.exports = class DB {  
.....   
  getCustomers(){  
    var result = this.db.exec("SELECT * FROM customers");  
    return result[0];  
  }  
};`  
  
To make it available from the GUI Code I've to:  
  
`ipc.on('db-getCustomers', function (event, arg) {  
  event.returnValue = dataBase.getCustomers();  
});`  
  
So I've to add an EventCallback to every DB Method I have.

Comment: Edits for legibility.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I fixed it by my own.
I'm no using only one ipc Callback and let it forward the required Method to an switch case within Database class.

Thanks all!